# Vectorizing for-loop in R for creating strings with different length

Tags: r, vectorization

I have created a sample R script to show my question:

```
test.df <- data.frame(uid=c('x001','x002','x003'),
                      start_date=c('2015-01-02','2015-03-05','2015-07-09'),
                      end_date=c('2015-01-07','2015-03-07','2015-07-16'),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
test.df[,'start_date'] <- as.Date(test.df[,'start_date']) 
test.df[,'end_date'] <- as.Date(test.df[,'end_date']) 
for (loop in (1:nrow(test.df))) {   
    test.df[loop,'output'] <- paste(seq(test.df[loop,'start_date'],test.df[loop,'end_date'],by = 1),collapse=';') 
}
```

I need to create strings of date with different length, I can only think of using `for-loop` for my problem, but I have about 70K cases that need to process the string, is there any way of speeding it up?

#### Update 01

Thanks @akrun for the answer, I have further modified my question as below:

```
library(dplyr)

test.df <- data.frame(uid=c('x001','x002','x003'),
                      start_date=c('2015-01-02','2015-03-05','2015-07-09'),
                      end_date=c('2015-01-07','2015-03-07','2015-07-16'),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
test.df[,'start_date'] <- as.Date(test.df[,'start_date'])
test.df[,'end_date'] <- as.Date(test.df[,'end_date'])

# Part A
for (loop in (1:nrow(test.df))) {   
  test.df[loop,'output'] <- paste(seq(test.df[loop,'start_date'],test.df[loop,'end_date'],by = 1),collapse=';') 
}

# Part B
test.mod <- group_by(test.df,uid) %>%
  do({df <- data.frame(.)
  output.df <- data.frame(uid=df[1,'uid'],
                          date=unlist(strsplit(df[,'output'],';')))
  data.frame(output.df)
  })
```

Now `Part A` is fixed, but is there anyway to speed up `Part B`? Or should I combine `Part A` and `Part B` together? Please enlighten me as `data.table` is new to me.

Comment: If you want to get sequence by row, you can either use `for` or one of the apply functions.  But, it wont change the speed

Comment: thanks @akrun, I used `dplyr` and yes, it takes some time to run the script, any other suggestions?

Comment: It may be better to use `data.table`.  In `dplyr`, you may need `do`, which would still be slower.  Posted a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could convert the 'test.df' to 'data.table' (`setDT(test.df)`), grouped by 'uid', we get the `seq` of 'start_date', 'end_date' and the `paste` the elements together.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test.df)[,paste(seq(start_date, end_date, by = '1 day'), collapse=';') , uid]
```

#### Update

For the Part B, if we dont `paste`, it is a two column dataset

```
setDT(test.df)[,seq(start_date, end_date, by = '1 day') , uid]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with apply

```
test.df <- data.frame(uid=c('x001','x002','x003'),
                      start_date=c('2015-01-02','2015-03-05','2015-07-09'),
                      end_date=c('2015-01-07','2015-03-07','2015-07-16'),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

test.df$output <- apply(test.df, 1, function(x) paste(seq(as.Date(x[2]), as.Date(x[3]), by = 1), collapse=';'))
```